# Como alterar posição do menu com framework materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Alguém sabe como colocar o slide sempre no topo e tudo o resto(menu, texto, etc...) depois do slide?

exemplo: http://99webpage.com/theme-review/html/tooku/index.html

Usando a framework: meterialize

```
<div class="slider fullscreen">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
              <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption left-align">
              <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption right-align">
              <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
              <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

                   <div class="navbar-fixed left">
                    <nav>
                      <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
```

O problema é que o menu fica sempre sobre o slide e eu quero algo como no exemplo que envio.

Comment: Poderias adicionar o código relevante daquilo que já tens até agora? E se possível também aprimorar a pergunta, porque no título mencionas uma coisa, e no corpo da pergunta parece que estás a questionar outra.

Comment: Já editei a questão e coloquei o código que tenho.

Comment: Acredito que Isso já resolva seu problema http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNgMEe